# Consumindo REST no Wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, spring, rest

Bom dia!

Implementei uma API Rest com Spring e gostaria de consumi-la em um site dentro do Wordpress.

Isso é feito por meio de Plugins ou direto com código dentro do Post?

Para um Post Request, como linkaria os dados de um formulário na requisição http?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você "implementou uma API Rest" eu acho que só tá faltando vc conhecer os métodos nativos do WP para fazer requisições:

[`wp_remote_get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/)

[`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/)

Por debaixo do capô eles fazem mais ou menos a mesma coisa, usam o mesmo método pra fazer requisições externas, e você passa nos argumentos o tipo de requisição (POST, PUT, UPDATE, etc), os cabeçalhos e demais informações.

exemplo da documentação:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.html', $args );

if ( is_array( $response ) && ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $headers = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
    $body    = $response['body']; // use the content
}
```

Comment: Boa noite!
Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Entendi. Minha dúvida é realmente como consumir esses dados retornados pela API em Json.

Pensei q houvesse uma forma mais alto nível, no entanto devo utilizar código PHP. Vou pesquisar como fazer isso pois não tenho experiência.

Mas como eu faço o binding do data para os inputs ou tables?

Abço.